# How to convert x/y pixels into lat/long before the map is ready?

Tags: leaflet, latitude-longitude

I have a custom layer which needs to be able to translate the requested tiles coordinates into lat/long.

```
  L.GridLayer.CanvasCircles = L.GridLayer.extend({
    createTile: function (coords) {
        console.log("coords", coords);
        if (window.map && window.map.layerPointToLatLng) {
          let latLng = window.map.layerPointToLatLng(coords);
          console.log("latLng", latLng);
        } else {
          console.log("No latLng yet");
        }
        ...
```

Unfortunately map.layerPointToLatLng() (and the reverse) are only available once the map is created.

```
    // Create the overall Leaflet map using the two layers we created.
    let map = window.map = new L.Map('map', {
      center: centre,
      zoom: 15,
      layers: [baseLayer, heatmap]
    })
```

Creating the map calls `createTile()` in my custom layer, but the map is not available yet, so my layer has to be blank on the first display of the map.

How can I fix this?

Are there any map-independent lat/long/z <-> x/y functions which I could use?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#crs contains the answer.

```
latLngToPoint(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom)   Point   
pointToLatLng(<Point> point, <Number> zoom)     LatLng
```

Now I just need to figure out which projection is used by default.  It seems to be EPSG:3857, but I'll need to check.

---

Yes, this does the job:

```
let latLng = L.CRS.EPSG3857.pointToLatLng(coords, coords.z);
```